# Using Bash variable indirection with combined variable

Tags: bash

I have a script that configured multiple "jobs" based on environment variables. The script performs internal iteration to and reads configuration from prefixed variables (e.g. `timeout_job_1=30`). Some, but not all, variables also have defaults, to be used when no job-specific one isn't available (e.g. `timeout=10`).

Example:

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash

#### Externally set variables
defaultValA="default value for A"
defaultValC="default value for C"
valA_1="A for iter 1"
valB_2="B for iter 2"

for((i=1; i<=2; i++)); do
  valA="valA_$i" ; valA="${!valA:-${defaultValA:-}}"
  valB="valB_$i" ; valB="${!valB:-${defaultValB:-}}"
  valC="valC_$i" ; valC="${!valC:-${defaultValC:-}}"

  echo "Iteration #$i val A: ${valA}"
  echo "Iteration #$i val B: ${valB}"
  echo "Iteration #$i val C: ${valC}"

  echo "---------"
done
```

**Is there a way to avoid the temporary variables on top of the loop, and somehow assign `valA`-`valC` directly?** I can use `eval` but that doesn't seem elegant.

Comment: Any time you think you need to create a variable name on the fly is generally a big clue that you should be using associative arrays instead. `declare -A timeouts; timeout[job_1]=30` etc

Comment: @Shawn: I fully agree on principle. However, many tools (including very popular ones like Docker Compose as per https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/4249) do not support any arrays, even simple lists. In addition, in this case it would make sense to use nested associative array in a form of job[0][timeout], which even bash will not support. This is why the whole code uses suboptimal dynamic variable names.

Comment: @kiler129: `docker-compose` is primary meant for testing purpose. Better use `docker run` with proper arguments, and associative arrays in a bash script if required.

Comment: You can usually emulate multidimensional arrays in bash very effectively with a single associative array by creating compound keys. `echo ${v[1,0]} # one, zero` This is efficient, and though it needs careful quoting in some cases, is simpler that multiple compound indirection, and likely a lot easier to maintain and debug. This will be a nightmare behind layers of container, yaml, possibly helm, dockerfiles, sidecars, and more...

Comment: Since `i` is a "small" integer, why aren't you using indexed arrays, so that you hav `valA=${valA_[$i]:-default}?

Answer (score 2):

Using a one dimensional associative array with compound keys to emulate multidimensional lookups.

```
declare -A v=( ["A,0"]="default value for A" 
               ["A,1"]="A for iter 1" 
               ["B,2"]="B for iter 2" 
               ["C,0"]="default value for C" ) # leaving holes is fine
for i in 1 2
do for l in A B C
   do echo $i,$l: ${v["$l,$i"]:-${v["$l,0"]}}
   done
done
1,A: A for iter 1
1,B:
1,C: default value for C
2,A: default value for A
2,B: B for iter 2
2,C: default value for C
```

No temp vars beside the loop iterators, no `eval`.